# strtotime calculates wrong when moving over to linux (webhost) from windows (localhost)

Tags: php

I've some problem with make a simple PHP function to work on my webspace meanwhile it works like expected at my localhost server.

The problem is the following calculation:

```
echo $Formated = date("Ymd",strtotime("last day of next month"));
```

This script dosen't seem to work b/c i simply gets the default date `19691231` instead of the correct one `20110630` when running it on my server.

I use windows (XAMP) as my localhost server so i guess there must be some form of problem that lies within the two platforms way of handling it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error on Debian Squeeze. What's the current time on the server machine? What's the locale on the server?

Comment: yep, it returns 19700101 on my linux test server(ubuntu server used here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime` is notoriously problematic going cross-version, so I'd recommend a vast simplification.  You can use the 't' character in the date format to represent the last day of the month, then reduce your strtotime call to simply return some timestamp for the next month.

```
echo $Formated = date("Ymt", strtotime("next month"));
```

Comment: @diEcho thanks for the +1 vote of confidence.  It should be much more reliable ... going forward aswell, on the offchance that strtotime changes in a future version.  They've done it before :P

Comment: Thanks for the help "Ymt" alternative

Answer (score 1):

dont use `of` if month name is not given

try with

```
 date('m/d/y', strtotime('last day next month')); 

 OR

 date('m/d/y', strtotime('last day of march'));  // give the month name with of
```

### [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#96095)

Answer (score 0):

Forget Migration and Deployment, in fact `strtime` is not reliable. Navigate PHP's official site: Check the [strtotime manual, especially this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#88679).

If you have a MySQL connection available, SELECT DATE_ADD( '2011-05-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) would be less redundant since the (correct) functionality is already implemented without you having to implement it yourself.